# Problem in websocket connection Xampp and PHP

Tags: php, websocket, xampp, localhost

I saw a simple and easy tutorials here - https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/ and exactly follow all the things I downloaded the files and pasted in my C://xampp/htdocs/chatsystem/ folder and I tried to start the websocket server which is php-socket.php file and open index.php file but the connection is refused

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8090/chatsystem/php-socket.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And here is my new websocket code in index.php

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8090/chatsystem/php-socket.php");
```

I did everything but unable to solve this issue

Comment: and... how do you start the websocket server?

Comment: by opening the xampp command prompt by clicking on the shell button and typing the address of php-socket.php file

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\chatsystem\php-socket.php and then clicked enter but then nothing is shown process on command prompt is this correct? I am new in this

Comment: check your `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` file. If there is a semicolon (`;`) in front of `extension=sockets`, remove it. 
And did you allow your firewall to allow connections to this port?
And how did you open you `index.php` file in the browser? via the server or via the file system?

Comment: No the semicolon is a already removed and i have this in php.ini file extension=php_sockets.dll instead of extension=sockets and I don't know about the firewall how to check that i just enter the path in the browser http://localhost/chatsystem/index.php that's it